# biblatex: Use field value in tex document before compilation

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to create a timeline of some publications. Since each publication includes information about its publication time, I want to use that information automatically to place the reference on the timeline.

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{chronology}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\newcommand{\paperevent}[1]{%
    \event{\citeyear{#1}}{\textcite{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{chronology}[5]{1960}{2013}{\textwidth}
    \paperevent{Miller1960}
\end{chronology}

\end{document}
```

As you might guess, this doesn't work, probably because `\citeyear` is not known during the first LaTeX compilation. Is there any way I can make this work using biblatex macros?

The error currently sounds:

```
There were errors in your LaTeX source

./timeline.tex:15: Extra \else. [    \paperevent{Miller1960}]
./timeline.tex:15: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `M' or `Mi' (in '(\citeyear {Miller1960}-1960)*\unit '). [    \paperevent{Miller1960}]
```

Comment: Note that `\citeyear` requires an argument. Some error persist if I substitute `\citeyear{#1}` for `\citeyear` in your code, though.

Comment: Of course, how stupid of me. I will edit the question.

Comment: The problem is that, on your first run of `pdflatex`, `\citeyear{Miller1960}` result in the BibTeX key (`Miller1960`) as opposed to simply `1960`. `Miller1960` is used as a placeholder for the actual year, because the bibliography information has not been retrieved from your .bib file yet, since BibTeX hasn't been called yet. Unfortunately, `\event` requires a number for its first mandatory argument. `Miller1960` is obviously not a number and generates an error, which prevents from getting past that first run of `pdflatex`.

Comment: A quick, albeit not very maintainable workaround, would be to modify the definition of `\paperevent` so as to hardcode the year:  `\newcommand{\paperevent}[2]{\event{#1}{\textcite{#2}}}`. Then you can use `\paperevent{1960}{Miller1960}`. Alternatively, if all your BibTeX keys all use the same naming convention and end by the year of publication, you could extract the year from that key (using `xstring`, for instance).  I'm sure others will come up with a better solution, but I can't think of any just now.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I would rather not split the bibtex key, the method is somewhat unsave. I thought one could move the output of \paperevent to some biblatex code, so that it is only printed after biblatex ran.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about defining a custom citation command for events:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{chronology}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\eventcite}{}{\event{\thefield{year}}{\printnames{labelname},\space\printfield{year}}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{chronology}[5]{1960}{2013}{\textwidth}
  \eventcite{Milnor:Morse}
\end{chronology}

\end{document}
```

with `refs.bib` containing

```
@Book{Milnor:Morse,
  author =   {Milnor, J.},
  title =    {Morse theory},
  publisher =    {Princeton University Press},
  year =     1973,
  volume =   51,
  series =   {Annals of Mathematics Studies},
  address =  {Princeton, New Jersey},
}
```

You will have to the usual `pdflatex biber pdflatex` sequence of compilations to get this to work.  The code assumes that the year field contains a simple year.

The command use `\thefield{year}` to get the year literally in the first argument.  In the second argument we want to print information from the citation so `\printnames{labelname}` and `\printfield{year}` are appropriate.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I tried using DeclareCiteCommand before, but for some reason didn't succeed. Thank you!